# basic qplot error using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling with why this basic qplot() isn't working for me. Data is as follows:

```
user_misclassification_rate = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2)
y_values = as.data.frame(user_misclassification_rate)
y_values$users = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
colnames(y_values)[1] = "error_rate"

my_barplot = qplot(x = users,
                   y = error_rate,
                   data = y_values,
                   geom="bar")

print(my_barplot)
```

it seems basic enough but i get the error Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic., which I am struggling to understand. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

edit: i know it's probably a silly mistake, i'm still looking online for what i'm doing wrong, but don't downvote just because its probably a simple / stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big user of qplot so not sure whether the `stat = 'identity'` argument can be passed in. By default a ggplot bar returns counts.

Think this is what you want in 'proper' ggplot:

```
ggplot(y_values, aes(users, error_rate)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Edit: the qplot vignette makes no mention of this - http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/qplot.html